# Python Socket Programming: sending and receiving int data between server and client?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm working on some code which establishes a client and server using `socket` for python. I want to take user input in my client, send that data over to my server, and then have the server send that info back into my client and store it as an `int`

Here is my server code:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 8890))

s.listen(5)
while True:
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection established from address {addr}")
    choice = s.recv(2048)
    conn.send(str(choice).encode('utf8'))
    conn.close()
```

Here is my code for the client side:

```py
import socket

choice = input("Select: ")

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 8890))

s.send(str(choice).encode('utf8'))

msg = s.recv(2048)
strings = msg.decode('utf8')
num = int(strings)
```

Currently, this code gives me this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/test/client.py", line 12, in <module>
    msg = s.recv(2048)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It was pretty close to working. On the server side `choice = s.recv(2048)` should be `choice = conn.recv(2048)`. Also `s.listen()` and `conn, addr = s.accept()` should be outside the loop.

```
#the server
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 8890))

s.listen()
conn, addr = s.accept()
with conn:
    
    print(f"Connection established from address {addr}")
    while True:
        choice = conn.recv(2048)
        if not choice:
            break
        conn.send(str(choice).encode('utf8'))

#the client
import socket

choice = input("Select: ")

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 8890))

s.send(str(choice).encode('utf8'))

msg = s.recv(2048)
strings = msg.decode('utf8')
# not sure if best solution but it's a quick fix
cleaned_num = int(strings.strip("b\'"))
print(f"Number is: {cleaned_num} ")
```

[Sources](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/)

Comment: Amazing, the data seems to be transferring. However, I can't find a way to save the data as an int which is what I need for the rest of my program, I'm getting an error ```ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "b'1'"```

Comment: @giotto1 Edited to include fix. `cleaned_num = int(strings.strip("b\'"))` should clean the output and allow the conversion to an int. Not sure if it's the right way to go about it but it works in this use case.